# Opinions on Uptrends vs Dynatrace Keynote for Website Monitoring?

Tags: javascript, performance, website-monitoring

Any suggestions on what would be a better fit for a retail website monitoring would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per Gartner you need to cover 4 important dimensions in order to cover Digital Experience fully.

1. Availability - can use both solutions for that
2. Errors - This is a case where you should look for Real User Monitoring solutions because you won't be able to configure all your real users environments in any of the solutions. Also think about tracking down server side errors which leads you to full APM solutions that also cover the server side
3. Performance - In an modern environment you need a mix of clean room/baseline (Synthetic) data points and real life (Real User Monitoring) data points.
4. Business Results - is only achievable via Real User Monitoring

If you only want to cover Availability you can use both but if you need to cover any of the other - Dynatrace is the more complete solution that gives you more head room for the future.